# Photoshop aligning easier

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Imagine the icons in the Tumblr homepage, http://www.tumblr.com/ the container is 365 in width and 38 in height.

Lets say we create a container in Photoshop, and we put all the icons in, how could I align them the quickest way?

One way of doing this is, 265 / 5 (icon count) = 53 so we can create a "helper" layer, with the size of 53px in width and 38px in height, then we could get each icon in the helper layer, center align it, and then when finished put them next to each other and remove the helper layers.

But this takes alot of time for such easy task, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Align function! Here is  step-guide for you:

**START**

[image: Step1]

**STEP 1 - place the left and right icons correctly**
Simply place the first icon correctly on the left side horizontally and make sure the right-most icon is placed perfectly too. Place the remaining three icons in-between.

[image: Step2]

**STEP 2** Then select all icons and align by vertical centres.

[image: Step3]

**STEP 3** Use distribute widths to force the icons to distribute nicely and perfectly.

[image: Step4]

Hope that helps!